# How to include .java files as embedded resources in Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to include some files as embedded resources in an Eclipse Java project, so that at runtime I can read them using

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("somefile")
```

For most files this works just by adding them to a directory inside the project, but some of the files to have the extension ".java". Eclipse naturally tries to compile them as part of the project. How do I tell it not compile them, but include them as embedded resources?

Comment: Is it a Maven project?

Comment: No, just running from Eclipse. I'll want to generate a JAR later, though.

Comment: If you create the project as a Maven project, you can just put the file in the `src/main/resources` and it won't compile. I just tried it. I'm not sure where you would put it in a regular java project though.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate folder and add it to your classpath as a library. See *Add Class Folder* in the [Java Build Path Page](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm?cp=1_4_9_0_0_0).

For example, I added a folder called *res* and changed my *.classpath* file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="res"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

You may have to script building the JAR externally to include only the non-compiled sources.